# Google Places Javascript API not making some requests

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I am using the [Google Places API for Javascript](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchRequests) to make lots of searches based on keywords.

All requests are of this format:

```
var request = {
        location: new google.maps.LatLng(40.711646, -74.016867),
        radius: 50000,
        keyword: "LAFAYETTE HIGH SCHOOL"
}

service.nearbySearch(request, 
function(response) { 
    console.log(response) 
} );
```

The above is repeated over 450 times, with different keywords.

If I enter any of the requests in the console they *works just fine*, and log valid responses in the console.

However, when I actually visit the site with all of  these requests, I can see in the Network tab that only a few of the requests are made. Most requests don't show up at all in the Network tab, and the console returns *null*.

This working of *some* requests but not *others* seems very strange to me. How can I get the Places API to properly place all requests and return the responses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are being throttled for sending too many requests in a row. Check the `PlacesServiceStatus` value in your `nearbySearch()` callback. If it is `google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` then you are being throttled. You will need to slow down your requests, but 450 places in a row for one user visit is a lot of requests! I'm not sure what to suggest other than to make these calls on your server and cache them.

Comment: Ah, that's definitely the culprit, thanks. Since the dataset I'm requesting is static, I think I'll call make the huge request once and save it as a CSV file. Thank you!

Comment: That is definitely the way to do it. When you make the requests from your server, wait a few seconds between requests. I'd make it five seconds in between, that should avoid throttling and will still let you geocode everything in several minutes.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up making the requests on the client side, appending each to a textarea in CSV format and then simply pasting it into a file on the server. An interval of 1 second was enough.